# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: < When sending base64 data to NodeJS backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

If a base64 string is manually defined as a const, then the following code works fine. However, when I switch to using state, then I get the error `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: <`. Below is the full code for selecting and then uploading images. I don't know why it doesn't work when using state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  PixelRatio,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
export default class Project extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      ImageSource: null,

      data: null,

      Image_TAG: "",

      ImageData: null,

      imageInfo: null,

      ServerImage: null,
    };
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    // Camera roll Permission
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
    // Camera Permission
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA,
      Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING
    );
    this.setState({ hasPermission: status === "granted" });
  };

  handleCameraType = () => {
    const { cameraType } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      cameraType:
        cameraType === Camera.Constants.Type.back
          ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
          : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
    });
  };

  pickImage = async () => {
    let response = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true,
    });
    if (!response.canceled) {
      this.setState({
        ImageSource: response.uri,
        data: response.data,
        ImageData: response.assets[0].base64,
        imageInfo: response.assets[0],
      });
    }
  };

  getImage = async () => {
    const mybody = {};
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://coral-app-n96bn.ondigitalocean.app/groupchat/getimage`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: mybody,
      }
    );
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      ServerImage: jsonData[0].image_base64,
    });
  };

  uploadImageToServer = async () => {
    let apiUrl = `https://coral-app-n96bn.ondigitalocean.app/groupchat/uploadimage`;
    const uri = this.state.ImageSource;
    const myBase64 = this.state.ImageData;

    let options = {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ uri: uri, base64: myBase64 }),
    };

    return fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("status: " + response.status);
        console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pickImage.bind(this)}>
          <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
            {this.state.ImageSource === null ? (
              <Text>Select a Photo</Text>
            ) : (
              <Image
                style={styles.ImageContainer}
                source={{ uri: this.state.ImageSource }}
              />
            )}
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Image Name "
          onChangeText={(data) => this.setState({ Image_TAG: data })}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          style={styles.TextInputStyle}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.uploadImageToServer}
          activeOpacity={0.6}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> UPLOAD IMAGE TO SERVER </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.getImage}
          activeOpacity={0.6}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Get Image from SERVER </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
          {this.state.ServerImage === null ? (
            <Text>Server photo will appear here</Text>
          ) : (
            <Image
              style={styles.ImageContainer}
              source={{
                uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.ServerImage}`,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
          {this.state.ImageData === null ? (
            <Text>Selected photo will appear here</Text>
          ) : (
            <Image
              style={styles.ImageContainer}
              source={{ uri: this.state.ImageData }}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#FFF8E1",
    paddingTop: 20,
  },

  ImageContainer: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    borderColor: "#9B9B9B",
    borderWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#CDDC39",
  },

  TextInputStyle: {
    textAlign: "center",
    height: 40,
    width: "80%",
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#028b53",
    marginTop: 20,
  },

  button: {
    width: "80%",
    backgroundColor: "#00BCD4",
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 20,
  },

  TextStyle: {
    color: "#fff",
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

This is the backend controller:

```
module.exports.uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
  const uploadImageQuery = await pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO practice_pics(image, image_base64) values($1, $2) RETURNING id",
    [req.body.uri, req.body.base64]
  );

  const newImage = uploadImageQuery.rows[0].id;

  res.json({
    ...req.body,
    body: req.body,
    status: newImage,
  });
};
```

I'm using Expo (react native) and an express server with Postgres database.

Comment: Have you printed `state.ImageData` to ensure that it contains what you think it contains?  It looks like you have pulled some HTML instead of base64 data.

Comment: 99.999% of the time `Unexpected token: <` means the server sent you html

Comment: When I do `console.log("state image data is: " + this.state.ImageData);`, I get `state image data is: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAALuKADAAQAAAABAAAH0gAAAAD/wAARCAfSC7gDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwA... (result truncated)` and that is base64, not html, correct?

Comment: The error is likely that `.then((response) => response.json())` this reponse is not json ... depends on which line of your code the error is caused by

Comment: Ok, good catch. I will remove that. I think the error also stems from the data being sent to the backend, because when I check my database, nothing is uploaded (before, when I would have `const myBase64 = enter_base64_here_without_using_state`, the uri and base64 would be correctly inserted into my database).